# How do Clip a Control [like Image] in to a Path /Shape [like Star/Round]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have `clipped` an `Image control` in to a `Border` which contains it by referring this [blog](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/)

Sample `xaml` Code

```
        <Border Behaviors:ImageClip.ToBounds="True">
            <Image  Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </Border>
```

But how do i `clip` an `Image Control` into a `Path / Shape`  [Like Star /Ellipse] .I have tried previous method.But it was not succeeded because path does not have `Content` Property so that we can't set `Image Clip Behaviour` to `Path`.
I have tried with `ImageBrush` Fill .But that could not fit into my case beacause i have to implement some `behaviours` like Pinch & Zoom on `Image Control`. 
So that am stuck.
Can anyone help me with any suggestion or samples?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just taking a path / shape and setting the background or fill properties to an image brush?

See: [How to Use an image as ImageBrush on a Line or Path in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641404/how-to-use-an-image-as-imagebrush-on-a-line-or-path-in-wpf)

Comment: yes i did it ; But i do want to achieve some behaviours like Pinch & Zoom on Image. So that am stuck.

Comment: @asitis ah I see, might be worth putting that in your actual question.

Comment: yea i include it into the question. Thanks.